# Changes from SQL Query and Update Statement

Tags: t-sql, random

I have a query that produces a random departure dates from 1 to 28 days after the arrival date field:

```
--Query--

SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
```

However when I run the Update query the randomisng reduced down to 1 or 2 days, can anyone advise why this is?

```
--Update Statement--

USE Occupancy
Update B
Set DepartureDate = DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5 * L.LengthofStay, B.ArrivalDate)
FROM LengthOfStay L, Bookings B
```

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: The two formulas are different: in the second one there is "*1.5". Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: I have put a simplified version on SQL fiddle, but I do not see what the problem may be: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/361ef/6 Maybe you can explain some more?

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution below:

```
UPDATE BOOKINGS 
SET DepartureDate = 
DATEADD(day, 
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0 and 0.3 THEN 2 ELSE 
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0.3 and 0.5 THEN 3 ELSE 
Round(Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 28,0) END END,ArrivalDate)
```